# Setting up QGIS Python scripts in Docker container

Tags: pyqgis, standalone, docker

I am trying to set up QGIS within a Docker container in order to run standalone Python scripts, but I have a few problems.

- I first had a `No module named PyQt5.sip` error which I fixed by adding PyQt5 in my requirements.txt file
- Then I had a `No module named qgis.core` which I fixed by adding a whole bunch of paths at the beginning of my script (see below)
- But now I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis._core'` for which I can't find a fix...

I tried to build a Dockerfile closer to what is recommended [here](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu) but that seemed to put me further from my goal with libgdal30, libproj22 and many other libraries not being able to be installed. I also have GDAL installed, which might be a reason for these errors.

#### Dockerfile

```dockerfile
# Use an official Python runtime as the base image
FROM python:3.10

RUN  pip install --upgrade pip

# Install QGIS
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y python3-launchpadlib \
    && apt-get install -y software-properties-common \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y qgis \
    && apt-get install -y qgis-plugin-grass

# Set environment variables for QGIS
ENV QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=/usr

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install any necessary Python dependencies from requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Run your Python script
CMD ["python3", "script.py"]
```

#### Python script

```python
import sys

sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python310.zip')
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python3.10')
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload')
sys.path.append('/home/timothee/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages')
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages')
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages')
sys.path.append("/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis")
sys.path.append("/usr/lib/python3/")
sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/')
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/qgis/')
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/')
import qgis.core
print(qgis.core.Qgis.QGIS_VERSION)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/make_tiles_scheduler.py", line 21, in <module>
    from make_tiles import *
  File "/app/make_tiles/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .make_tiles import make_tiles
  File "/app/make_tiles/make_tiles.py", line 16, in <module>
    import qgis.core
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/core/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from qgis._core import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis._core'
```

Comment: And why not use the official image : https://hub.docker.com/r/qgis/qgis ?

Comment: Official image are too big in my opinion, I'm not using them when I can. (I still use them for some use-case). The 3.28 official image is 8.51GB... My answser is 1.12GB for the 3.28 image.

Comment: You can have a look to the dockerfile : https://github.com/3liz/docker-qgis-platform/ `docker run -it -v $PWD:/scripts 3liz/qgis-platform:3.28 python3 /scripts/script.py` will execute the `script.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, using an official QGIS Docker image works great.

### Dockerfile

```dockerfile
# Use an official QGIS image
FROM qgis/qgis

# Set environment variables for QGIS
ENV QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=/usr
ENV QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen
ENV XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/tmp/runtime-root

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install any necessary Python dependencies from requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Run your Python script
CMD ["python3", "script.py"]
```

### docker-compose.yml

```yml
  python-script:
    image: qgis:latest
    build:
      context: ./directory
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - .env
```